# Making a Game Like Pineapple Pen in libgdx - But game is too easy

Tags: game-design, difficulty

It is kind of like a theoretical question.

I was trying to make a game like Pineapple Pen just for the sake of learning libgdx more and just for fun .

Pineapple Pen is pretty hard game but there is not much to write code in it as there is a object which keeps on moving to its x-axis and there is a pen at the bottom and you have to tap the screen to hit the pineapple. <--- This game is quite hard

But the game that I made which is quite similar to the Pineapple Pen, is very easy like one can always expect when can you hit the pineapple.

I am guessing there is a theory behind all this which beyond my understanding, anyone can shed some light in this topic?

Answer (score 1):

The difficulty of your game will depend on a couple of time intervals. The first time interval is the maximum amount of time between the pineapple appearing and the player tapping and successfully hitting the pineapple. The second one is the window between the earliest and latest times the player can tap and score a hit.

Understanding how you can adjust either or both of these time intervals will help you tune your game. Some factors will be:

- the movement speeds of the pineapple and pen
- the collision shapes for the pineapple and pen
- the distance between where the pineapple appears and where it can be hit by the pen

If you want to start by reproducing the original game, examine it carefully to figure some of those things out. You can always learn from other designs, even if you decide later to go in a different direction.

Comment: Another item to consider is adding variability to the speeds, sizes, distances, etc. For any fixed set of parameters, the player can learn one timing and then it's just down to their reaction speed whether they can hit it. When the parameters vary, the player needs to observe each item and apply some judgement to predict when they should fire.